# passing one function variable as a argument to another function of a Class

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. What i am trying i have performed insertion and i will have to grab the its id so i used ;insert_lastid(); function which is same as mysqli_last_insert_id ,so dont get confused with it .i tried to hold that last id on basis of last id i will perform select  operation in another function 
Here is the code which will clear more my problem . This function is for  insertion

```
public function cars_insert($_POST,$path) {
    $this->insert_query="insert into `_cars` (`_year`,`_make`,`_model`,`_version`,`_city`,`_color`,`_mileage`,`_engine_capacity`,                                                                                 `_engine_type`,`_assembly`,`_image`)VALUES('" .$_POST['year'] . "','" .$_POST['make'] . "','" .$_POST['model'] . "','" .$_POST['version'] . "','" .$_POST['city'] . "','" .$_POST['color'] . "','" .$_POST['mileage'] . "','" .$_POST['engine_capacity'] . "','" .$_POST['engine_type'] . "','" .$_POST['assembly'] . "','" .$path . "')";
    return $this->insert();
    global $car;
    $this->car=insert_lastid();
}
```

Here it is the second function it will Select on basis of `insert_lastid();`

```
 public function cars_id($this->car){
    $this->select_query="SELECT * FROM `_cars` WHERE `_id`='$this->car'";
    return $this->select();
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Are you really doing some code AFTER a return in a function ?

Comment: Are you new to PHP or new to programming? Are you posting to SO instead of learning how to program?

Comment: @OcuS yes i am trying to pass that this-car to function cars_id(), but maybe i am writing wrong syntax for that

Comment: @Barmar Give him/her sometime to settle with programming and SO :) Looks like Snow_ash struck a nerve :)

Comment: @Barmar True i need something to settle my problem which i am facing now

Comment: Sorry, I've been ornery today. I think it's crazy that so many people who have no idea how to program are in this position.

Comment: **You learn `programming` from BOOKS not SO.** SO should be used for edge cases :) not most basic of basic things.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the ID isn't being set is that you have a `return` statement before you set the variable. The moment you hit the `return` statement the function stops executing. Move  your code so that the variable assignment is done before the function returns.

```
$insert = $this->insert();
$this->car=insert_lastid();

return $insert;
```

Your `global $car` statement and the parameter in `cars_id` are both unnecessary because `$this->car` is a member of the class and is accessible from any member function of that class without having to be passed in or global'ed as you would with a normal variable.

```
public function cars_id(){
    $this->select_query="SELECT * FROM `_cars` WHERE `_id`='$this->car'";
    return $this->select();
}
```

As a side note, your code is currently **extremely vulnerable** to SQL injection attacks unless you have some kind of code in `$this->insert()` that is checking your SQL statements before running them. Make sure you properly escape all `$_POST` variables before using them in a query, or use prepared statements.

Comment: you mean by defining $car as global I didnt have to pass as argument and it is availble all over in the class and i can use it in a function :) just use it in a Where statement

Comment: Any variable that is a member of the class (i.e. accessed with `$this->`) can be accessed in any function that is also a member of that class without being passed to the function. For example if I have `class A` which has `$foo` and `bar()` as members, I can access `$foo` inside of `bar()` directly using `$this->foo` without having to pass it in.

Comment: the function can you use like $this->insert_lastid

Comment: @Snow_ash You need to accept answers as well..if it suffice for the query been posted.

Comment: @badwolf i am not getting the id not at all i have tried to make $this-car=22 but the query did work :(